# EJB 3 Stub generation

Tags: java, ejb

I have an ejb-3 compatible ejb, say

```
@Remote
interface Hai{
     String sayHai();
}
Stateless(name = "xxx", mappedname="yyy")
public class HaiImpl implements Hai{
    public String sayHai(){
        return "Hai";
    }
}
```

And I need to generate stub for this EJB. but I dont want to use websphere tool or maven tool.
Is there any way to generate stub using jdk?

When you create remote client

```
 Hai hai = (Hai)ctx.lookup("yyy#com.zz.Hai");
 System.out.println(hai.sayHai());
```

will work in weblogic or jboss, but in websphere, even it is ejb 3 you need to write like this

```
Object o = ctx.lookup("yyy");
Hai hai =    (Hai)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(o,Hai.class);
System.out.println(hai.sayHai());
```

In this case, if the stub is not presents at the client it will throw exception, there is a way to generate stub using websphere ejb stub generater tool. But I dont want to use any platform specific tools.

Comment: Is the need to generate stubs motivated by EJB 2.x interoperability or why you have to generate stubs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you must use WAS_HOME/bin/createEJBStubs.  The rmic command included in the Java SDK, which would normally be used to generate stubs, cannot be used on "pure" EJB 3 remote interfaces that do not extend java.rmi.Remote.

Note that if you use the application client container (WAS_HOME/bin/launchClient) or your "client" is another server, then you do not need to generate stubs: the container will generate one for you.  You only need to use createEJBStubs if you're using an unmanaged thinclient.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a [maven-plugin wrapper](https://github.com/lsiu/websphere-maven-plugin) for the createEJBStub script.

**Why?**

This allow us to build test maven projects which runs as part of our CI setup against our application after deployment.

More specifically together with maven, this allow our test project to:

1. Utilize Maven dependency management to pull the API jar which we publish to our internal nexus repository
2. Create Stub classes as part of the "generate-sources" maven life-cycle
3. Run junit test case against Application server with EJB to do integration testing.